# SQL How to extract first few & last few lines

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I write a query to extract data for:

25 orders for the first 5 days of the month AND 25 orders for the last 5 days of the month.

(I use Alibaba DataWorks/DataStudio. Postgres has the closest syntax)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What month are you talking about?  Are the "5" days calendar days or days with orders?  Can the orders all come from the same day?  What if there are not 25 orders in those time periods?

Comment: @GordonLinoff August-October 2020 (for these 3 months) Date format yyyy-mm-dd. First 25 orders that's within the first 5 days of the month & Last 25 orders that's within the last 5 days of the month.

Comment: . . This type of information belongs in the *question* not in a comment.  The question is lacking lots of useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill in with your columns and specific dates.

This solution uses two queries and combines their result. First part is for up to 25 orders for the first 5 days of the month while latter is for up to 25 orders for the last 5 days of the month.

```
select * 
from (
  select *
  from orders
  where datecolumn between 'start of month' and 'start of month' + interval '5 days'
  order by datecolumn asc
  limit 25
) t1
union all 
select * 
from (
  select *
  from orders
  where datecolumn between 'end of month' and 'end of month' - interval '5 days'
  order by datecolumn desc
  limit 25
) t2
```